# Scripting file copy with notification upon completion

Tags: shell, ubuntu, copy, backup

I am using Ubuntu to copy files contained within more than a hundred CD's to a single hard drive. When a CD's contents has finished copying to the hard drive, I receive no indication that it is done. I would like to create shell script that does the following:

1. Prompt me for a name to give a new folder
2. Create the folder on the destination hard drive
3. Copy the contents of CD currently in the cd drive to the new folder
4. Notify me when the copy operation is complete

I've installed libnotify onto my computer, but I'm open to using other means of notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r -p "Enter a folder name: " name
do
    [[ -z $name ]] && break    # quit if user presses enter without input
    mkdir -p "$name"
    cp source "$name"          # use your current copy method

    # Notifications: choose one or all six or add your own
    notify-send "Copy complete" "Folder: $name"
    zenity  --title="Copy complete" --text="Copying to folder $name is complete" --info&
    dialog --title "Copy complete" --msgbox "\nCopying to folder\n$name\nis complete\n" 10 60
    for i in {1..4}
    do
        printf '\a'            # make some noise
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "Copying to folder: $name is complete" | mail -S "Copy completion notification" keyslinger@example.com
    printf 'Copy to folder %s is complete.\n' "$name"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Dennis, it worked a charm! Just for reference, here's what I ended up using:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r -p "Enter a folder name: " name
do
    [[ -z $name ]] && break # quit if user presses enter without input
    cd /media/Iomega_HDD
    mkdir -p "$name"
    cdname=`volname`
    cdname=${cdname%% *}    #trim white space from variable holding cd name
    cdname=${cdname#* }
    cp -r /media/"$cdname"/. "$name"

    # Notifications:
    notify-send "Copy complete" "Folder: $name"
    printf 'Copy to folder %s is complete.\n' "$name"
    eject
done
```